# How can I add fade in, fade out effects

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-gallery

I have a simple script which works as a simple html gallery. However, I need to add some transition effects to my gallery, something like fade in, fade out, or the effect of something similar to the subtitles at the end of every movie (you know what I mean).

How can I solve this? I would like to make it using only JS, HTML, CSS, without external plugins. Is it possible? For now on, I have only something like this below:

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <script>
var images = [      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Example-zh.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/P%C5%99%C3%ADklad.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Beispiel.png"
         ];

var links = [       "http://www.example1.com",
            "http://www.example2.com",
            "http://www.example3.com",
            "http://www.example4.com", 
                "http://www.example5.com", 
            "http://www.example6.com",
         ];
var i = 0;
var renew = setInterval(function(){
        if(i==images.length) i=0;
        document.getElementById("img1").src = images[i]; 
    document.getElementById("link1").href = links[i]; 

        if(i+1==images.length) i=-1;
        document.getElementById("img2").src = images[i+1];
    document.getElementById("link2").href = links[i+1];

        if(i+2==images.length) i=-2;
        document.getElementById("img3").src = images[i+2];
    document.getElementById("link3").href = links[i+2];

        i+=3;


},5000);
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div align="center">
<a href="http://www.example1.com" id="link1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png" id='img1' > </a> </br></br>
<a href="http://www.example2.com" id="link2"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg" id='img2' > </a> </br></br>
<a href="http://www.example3.com" id="link3"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png" id='img3' > </a> </br>
</div> 

</body>
```

Comment: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ 
check it out please

Answer (score 4):

I just created a JQuery function and added it to your script. Now when you click on that button it will do as it says. It is just as an example how to do that

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <script>

var images = [      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Example-zh.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/P%C5%99%C3%ADklad.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Beispiel.png"
         ];

var links = [       "http://www.example1.com",
            "http://www.example2.com",
            "http://www.example3.com",
            "http://www.example4.com", 
                "http://www.example5.com", 
            "http://www.example6.com",
         ];
var i = 0;
var renew = setInterval(function(){
        if(i==images.length) i=0;
        document.getElementById("img1").src = images[i]; 
    document.getElementById("link1").href = links[i]; 

        if(i+1==images.length) i=-1;
        document.getElementById("img2").src = images[i+1];
    document.getElementById("link2").href = links[i+1];

        if(i+2==images.length) i=-2;
        document.getElementById("img3").src = images[i+2];
    document.getElementById("link3").href = links[i+2];

        i+=3;


},5000);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("#link1").fadeOut()
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $("#link1").fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div align="center">
<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>
<a href="http://www.example1.com" id="link1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png" id='img1' > </a> </br></br>
<a href="http://www.example2.com" id="link2"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg" id='img2' > </a> </br></br>
<a href="http://www.example3.com" id="link3"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png" id='img3' > </a> </br>
</div> 

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I think jQuery is overkill for this taks

Comment: @yak it can be done but you have to specify any event when it should be done

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely achieve some effects with CSS. But not all *(like jQuery-ui's blind)*

1. most effects consist of changing:

   - `opacity: [0-1]`
   - `display: relative; left: [X]px; top: [Y]px` or `transform: translate([X]px,[Y]px)`
   - `overflow: hidden`
   - and an animation:

either CSS:

```
#img {
  animation: fade-in 2s infinite;
} 

@keyframe fade-in { 
  from {
    left: -200px
  }
  to {
    left: 0 
  }
}`
```

or JavaScript:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
  (function(step) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      img.style.transform = "translate(-"+(200-step*2)+"px, 0)";
    }, step * 20);
  })(i);
}
```

2. to achieve something like blind, you must move an image-container <div> left, while moving the image right at the same speed.

   - Here's a simplified **blind** effect example
     https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/Lh10phuv/5/

Here I've implemented 8 pure JavaScript effects *(including blind, with instructions)*
  - **fade in**
http://codepen.io/warkentien2/pen/pboVXR
  - **fade out**
http://codepen.io/warkentien2/pen/EyxpVq

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. I have not changed your code at all.

HTML

```
<div align="center"> 
 <a href="http://www.example1.com" id="link1">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png" id='img1' > 
 </a> 
</br>
</br>
<a href="http://www.example2.com" id="link2">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg" id='img2' > 
</a>
<br>
<br>
  <a href="http://www.example3.com" id="link3">
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png" id='img3'>

 </a>
  <br>
  </div>
```

Css

```
  <style>
     .animate{transition:all 1s ease; opacity:0;}
  </style>
```

Js

```
  <script>
      var images = [          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Example_image.png",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Example-zh.jpg",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/P%C5%99%C3%ADklad.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Beispiel.png"
     ];

  var links = [       "http://www.example1.com",
              "http://www.example2.com",
             "http://www.example3.com",
              "http://www.example4.com", 
               "http://www.example5.com", 
               "http://www.example6.com",
             ];
     var i = 0;
    var renew = setInterval(function(){
      if(i==images.length) i=0;
    document.getElementById("img1").src = images[i]; 
        document.getElementById("link1").href = links[i];
            document.getElementById('link1').style.opacity = 0; 
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('link1').setAttribute("class", "animate");
                document.getElementsByClassName('animate')[0].style.opacity = 1;
                setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('link1').removeAttribute("class", "animate")},500)
            },500)


    if(i+1==images.length) i=-1;
    document.getElementById("img2").src = images[i+1];
        document.getElementById("link2").href = links[i+1];
            document.getElementById('link2').style.opacity = 0; 
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('link2').setAttribute("class", "animate");
                document.getElementsByClassName('animate')[1].style.opacity = 1;
                setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('link2').removeAttribute("class", "animate")},500)
            },500)

    if(i+2==images.length) i=-2;
    document.getElementById("img3").src = images[i+2];
        document.getElementById("link3").href = links[i+2];
            document.getElementById('link3').style.opacity = 0;
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('link3').setAttribute("class", "animate");
                document.getElementsByClassName('animate')[2].style.opacity = 1;
                setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('link3').removeAttribute("class", "animate")},500)
            },500)

    i+=3;



     },5000);
 </script>
```

Check live example here - https://jsfiddle.net/Rit_Design/9mkvffnk/1/

Remember the code can be much more smarter.